# Add .ics file to outlook without the user downloading it

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, icalendar, dday

I am writing an ASP.NET webapp together with some other students. We have to make it possible to schedule an appointment in outlook. So far we were able to create a .ics file with the dday iCalendar library. the user can download it and add it to outlook. is there a way to add the ics immediatly to the outlook calender withouth the user forcing to download it?

Comment: Are you specifying the correct content-type, i.e. "text/calendar" ?

Comment: I dont realy get what you want to say. I have the file and when the user opens it, he can add it to his calendar. now I want to make it that when you push the button it does not download the file but just adds it to the outlook calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the user is using IE and you site is added to the list of trusted sites. If these conditions are met, you can use the Outlook Object Model from your client side Java Script to create an instance of the [Outlook.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866895.aspx) object using `new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application')`. You can then call Application.CreateItem(1) (1 stands for the olAppointmentItem enum). Populate all the [AppointmentItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862177.aspx) properties and call [AppointmentItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862177.aspx).Save.